# php rest webservice

Tags: php, web-services, rest

how can i get a xml file when i pass a parameterized url

Comment: You're really going to have to give us a little more to work with. If you just want to get a file, you can use any of the regular file-opening commands on a URL, assuming that fopen wrappers are enabled (which is usually the case).

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the XML file in PHP, try setting the header as the first line of the script.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```